# Send and Receive JSON using an https curl_exec call in PHP

Tags: php, curl

I'm trying to make a curl call using PHP. My project has a flow like this

- I redirect user to the server.
- User uses the services and the server redirects him to a page on my application.
- I would like to make a server to server call at this point to verify certain details.

Point to be noted - I post JSON data as well as receive JSON data as response.

I have tried this. I am able to send data but don't get any response.

Is this correct?
Please help!

```
$data = array("One" => "Onedata", "Two" => "Twodata");                                                                    
$JsonData = json_encode($data);
$ch = curl_init('https://exampleurl');                                                                      
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, "POST");                                                                     
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $JsonData);                                                                  
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);                                                                      
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array(                                                                          
'Content-Type: application/json',  
'Content-Length: ' . strlen($JsonData))                                                                       
);                                                                                                                   

$result = curl_exec($ch);
```

Comment: There is no such thing as no response. If is fail, there is curl error message for you to check. If is success, there is also a status for you to check against.

Comment: Okay i used curl_getinfo($ch, CURLINFO_HTTP_CODE) and the response i got is 0. I suppose this means that the url is not accessible?firewall issues?

Comment: Also i checked for the error. this is the error that is sent back. "SSL certificate problem, verify that the CA cert is OK. Details: error:14090086:SSL routines:SSL3_GET_SERVER_CERTIFICATE:certificate verify failed"

Comment: Hey okay so i figured out the problem. SSL verification was the issue.I turned it off using curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, 0); curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, 0); Works now.

Comment: Worth posting an answer below to your own question and marking it correct, for those who follow.

Comment: I've posted your answer below and added a link to blog which describes how to enable https, rather than disable it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you mention in the comment:

The problem is with SSL verification of the host.  It takes some effort (see http://unitstep.net/blog/2009/05/05/using-curl-in-php-to-access-https-ssltls-protected-sites/) to setup SSL correctly, so a workaround is to add the following two options:

```php
curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, 0); 
curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, 0);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to use the below code which works for me. and make sure the json_url is correct. When you run it on the browser you should get an output. Before try it using CURL, run in on the browser and see whether you get the output you want.

```
$json_url  ='https://exampleurl';

// Initializing curl
$ch = curl_init( $json_url );

// Configuring curl options
$options = array(
CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => true,
CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER => array('Content-type: application/json') 
);

// Setting curl options
curl_setopt_array( $ch, $options );

// Getting results
$results =  curl_exec($ch); // Getting jSON result string

$json_decoded = json_decode($results);
```

Comment: Doesnt work. Still the same results.No response strign and status is 0..Thanks for the help though

Comment: Before try it using CURL, run in on the browser and see whether you get the output you want.