# receive json in php curl

Tags: php, json, curl

I try this code to send data and convert it to json.

```
$data = array();
$data['firstname']= "sample";
$data['lastname']="sampel lastname";

$post_str = '';

foreach($data as $key => $val){
   $post_str .= $key.'='.urlencode($val).'&';   
}

$post_str = substr($post_str,0,-1);


$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_URL,'http://localhost/receive_data_curl.php');

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array(                                                                          
    'Accept: application/json',                                                                         
    'Content-type: application/json')
); 
curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_POST,true);
curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS,$post_str);
curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER,true);
curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_HEADER,0);
$response = curl_exec($ch);

curl_close($ch);
```

My problem is how can i receive the data that i send through json? 
I have really no idea how can i fetch the data and the only code in my mind is header(). I watched other tutorial from youtube but i failed.

I tried this code to fetch the data without the CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER

```
$firstname = $_POST['firstname'];
$lastname = $_POST['lastname'];

$fh = fopen('receice.txt','w');
fwrite($fh,$firstname." = ".$lastname);
fclose($fh);
```

it is really working but if I add CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, it doesn't work.

here's the linux command code

```
curl - v 
- H "Accept: application/json" 
- H "Content-type: application/json" 
- X POST 
- d '{"cart" : 
        {"cancel_url":"http://yourdomain.com/your_cancel_url",
        "invoice":"11111111",
        "notes":"sample note",
        "success_url":"http://yourdomain.com/your_success_url",
        "total_amount":"30.0",
    }'
```

Comment: It doesn't look like you are sending JSON. You are sending the data as normal query string. So setting `'Content-type: application/json'` is definitely wrong. Are you asking how to access the sent data in `receive_data_curl.php`?

Comment: Why are you posting a query string?  POST should be sent as an array of key=>value pairs.

Comment: @RaggaMuffin-420: Typically POST data is sent as query string, at least if you are dealing with HTML forms. You can't send an "array", you have to serialize the data somehow.

Comment: but cURL formats the array for you... its just wasted process to loop data and format it yourself.. its backwards, just let C do it.

Comment: @RaggaMuffin-420: It seems to depend on how you want to send the data. Passing an array encodes the data as `multipart/form-data`. If you want `application/x-www-form-urlencoded`, you have to encode the data yourself. *"its just wasted process to loop data and format it yourself"* I think performance concerns are irrelevant at this point.

Comment: @FelixKling yes how can i access data from json that i send. Is it my code wrong?

Comment: *"it is really working but if I add CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, it doesn't work."* That's because you are telling PHP to expect JSON, even though you are not sending JSON. If the code works without the `'Content-type: application/json'` header, why do you want to set it at all? Why do you want to send the data as JSON if it works perfectly fine already?

Comment: @RaggaMuffin-420 Is it my code wrong?

Comment: @FelixKling i have linux comman code here that i want to convert it 
php and it add the - H "Accept: application/json" 
- H "Content-type: application/json"

Comment: Why didn't you post this in your question instead of the PHP script that does not send JSON? *edit:* Now I'm even more confused. Do you want to implement that `curl` command in PHP?

Comment: sorry for that @FelixKling. I add the command code, I edit my post already. see at the end of my post

Comment: Either way, I recommend you search for *"how to send JSON via curl in PHP"* (if you actually want to do that, I'm still not sure) and *"how to receive JSON in a POST request in PHP"*. Then you will find [Send and Recieve json using curl call in php](http://stackoverflow.com/q/14744781/218196) and [How to recieve a json encoded string POSTED and extract them into variables php](http://stackoverflow.com/q/22077935/218196)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You try below code for sending data

```
$data = array();
$data['firstname']= "sample";
$data['lastname']="sampel lastname";
$send_json_data = json_encode($data);

$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_URL,'http://localhost/receive_data_curl.php');

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array(                                                                          
    'Accept: application/json',                                                                         
    'Content-type: application/json')
); 
curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_POST,true);
curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS,$send_json_data);
curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER,true);
curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_HEADER,0);
$response = curl_exec($ch);

curl_close($ch);
```

And for receiving data

```
$json = file_get_contents('php://input');
$json_receive_data = json_decode($json,true);
$firstname = $json_receive_data['firstname'];
$lastname = $json_receive_data['lastname'];

$fh = fopen('receice.txt','w');
fwrite($fh,$firstname." = ".$lastname);
fclose($fh);
```